# Automatically disable JavaScript on Web Browser

Tags: browser

I need a way to "disable JavaScript" / "not run JavaScript" in the web browser.

Is it possible to do it using JavaScript or some other automatic way?

**Update:** reason for this? Easy, there are some "online TV sites" where they use several iframes pointing to "cross site urls" and it is annoying to get several "advertising" pop ups all the time. By coding my own webbrowser "add-on/extension" I've tried to "delete" html nodes and some Javascript and it works for the "main page" code, not for iframe "Cross Domain URL".... so I think disabling javascript AFTER the movie starts, would be a nice solution.

**Update 2:**
The video I want is a result of a iframe cascade chain.... I've tried all the way to "catch" the final "url" result using fiddler and other tools, but its getting hard since this different "cross domain" communication is sharing "runtime keys" to avoid what I want to accomplish (perhaps with more time I can do it) but this is why I thought that an easy and fast solution would be just disable javascript after the movie starts.

**NOTE**: other extensions such as Adblock and similars DO NOT work, since the website detect it and the video never loads.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Just don't send JavaScript - it wouldn't be executed! :)

Comment: There is no way you can do that.

Comment: @Dryadwoods Your original question did not make it clear that you're writing a browser add-on. I think many of the readers assumed you were creating a web-page and wanted to disable JavaScript in your client's browsers for some reason.

Comment: @iWerner this is why I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to programmatically disable the JavaScript on a user's browser using another JavaScript add-on/extension.

However, it may be possible if you use PHP as a proxy to intercept the pages you want, and strip out all script tags. You might even be able to extract the video URL you want and play it using another (flash?) player.

If you are a system administrator and want to disable JavaScript on all your network's computers, please post on SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable, but you can overwrite the javascript functions.
`alert = function(){}
alert("hello")`

You can even kill those iframes by tag name.

Comment: Yeah, but he means about an addon/extension. So it is possible.
Using Greasemonkey scripts to inject code or killing the iframes before they load.